# gnuplot with lines is not working

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having a very difficult time getting "with lines" to work with gnuplot 4.6. I have a the following styles

```
set style line 2  lc 7 lt 1 pt 7 lw 1.5
set style line 3  lc 1 lt 1 lw 4.0
```

and I use the following plot command

```
plot '-' using 1:2 w lp ls 2 title 'test1','-' using 1:3 w lp ls 3 title 'test2'
```

NOTE **lp** in second plot

everything works fine, but I want to remove the data points from the second plot, so I've tried the following command

```
plot '-' using 1:2 w lp ls 2 title 'test1','-' using 1:3 w l ls 3 title 'test2'
```

NOTE **l** in second plot

but it fails to plot anything. The legend indicates that the style was picked up correctly, but there is no plot.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to use "linepoints" and shut off the points? I just want a line in the second plot.

Comment: OK, so it seems to work fine if i write to a file instead of giving the input on the command line. I'm not sure why "linepoints" works and "lines" doesn't from the command line input.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some sample data for plotting.  Your commands are reading in their data interactively from stdin.  We have no way of knowing what the data you are trying to plot looks like.

Comment: The data doesn't matter. I'm using integer numbers generated in a for loop, say from 1:5. I pass the gnuplot commands above via pipe within a C program. As I said, everything works for "linepoints" but not for "lines". If I write the data to a file it works with "lines" as I hoped for, but I'd like to avoid having to write a bunch of temporary files.

Comment: Basically, I have a for loop that pipes data from an array to gnuplot. It pipes 3 values for each pass in the loop. I'm trying to plot 1:2 with "linepoints" and 1:3 with "lines". If I use "linepoints" for 1:3 it works, but not for "lines"

Comment: Are you pushing the data through twice?  With two plot commands reading from stdin, it is necessary to push the data through twice (once for each plot specification).  gnuplot will not "remember" the data from the earlier run.

Comment: Yes. I tried that. I pipe the 2 plot commands as shown above, then run through the loop once. I then follow up with a pipe "e" to end the data entry, then run through the loop again, and end with "e".

Comment: I don't have the code in front of me. I will post it tomorrow for more investigation if it's something that needs more insight.

Comment: Can you try to use the `'+'` special file? e.g. something like `plot '+' using 1:($1) w lp ls 2 title 'test1', '+' using 1:(2*$1) w lp ls 3 title 'test2'` ?

Comment: I figured it out. I was passing one to many "\n" characters to pipe. It's interesting that it worked with both commands being "linepoints" but when one was changed to "lines" it did not work. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Which question is the one we are talking about, on meta. You have 2 with no answers. Recently.

Comment: @Drew I found out what I was doing wrong with this question. The one I'm stuck on is this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952998/optimize-symbolic-integral-expression-with-matlab)

Comment: cuz I know two matlab guys. you all set ? Plus it has to age 2 days first. That one is 22hrs old (too early for a bounty). Unlike this one where the bounty link is live

Comment: @Drew OK. I guess I'll let that simmer for another day. I was unaware that there is a 2 day ageing period.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was passing one to many "\n" characters to pipe. It's interesting that it worked with both commands being "linepoints" but when one was changed to "lines" it did not work. Thanks for the input though.