# How do I optimize constrained integral expressions in MATLAB using anonymous functions?

Tags: matlab, optimization, functional-programming, anonymous-function

I have an integrated error expression *E = int[ abs(x-`p`)^2 ]dx* with limits *x|0* to *x|`L`*. The variable `p` is a polynomial of the form *2*(a*sin(x)+b(a)*sin(2*x)+c(a)*sin(3*x))*. In other words, both coefficients *b* and *c* are known expressions of `a`. An additional equation is given as *dE/da = 0*. If the upper limit `L` is defined, the system of equations is closed and I can solve for `a`, giving the three coefficients.

I managed to get an optimization routine to solve for `a` purely based on maximizing `L`. This is confirmed by setting `optimize=0` in the code below. It gives the same solution as if I solved the problem analytically. Therefore, I know the equations to solve for the coefficent `a` are correct.

I know the example I presented can be solved with pencil and paper, but I'm trying to build an optimization function that is generalized for this type of problem (I have a lot to evaluate). Ideally, `polynomial` is given as an input argument to a function which then outputs `xsol`. Obviously, I need to get the optimization to work for the `polynomial` I presented here before I can worry about generalizations.

Anyway, I now need to further optimize the problem with some constraints. To start, `L` is chosen. This allows me to calculate `a`. Once `a` is know, the `polynomial` is a known function of `x` only i.e `p(x)`. I need to then determine the largest INTERVAL from `0->x` over which the following constraint is satisfied: `|dp(x)/dx - 1| < tol`. This gives me a measure of the performance of the `polynomial` with the coefficient `a`. The interval is what I call the "bandwidth". I would like to emphasis two things: 1) The "bandwidth" is NOT the same as `L`. 2) All values of `x` within the "bandwidth" must meet the constraint. The function `dp(x)/dx` does oscillate in and out of the tolerance criteria, so testing the criteria for a single value of `x` does not work. It must be tested over an interval. The first instance of violation defines the bandwidth. I need to maximize this "bandwidth"/interval. For output, I also need to know which `L` lead to such an optimization, hence I know the correct `a` to choose for the given constraints. That is the formal problem statement. (I hope I got it right this time)

Now my problem is setting this whole thing up with MATLAB's optimization tools. I tried to follow ideas from the following articles:

- [Tutorial for the Optimization Toolbox™](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/tutorial-for-the-optimization-toolbox.html)

Setting `optimize=1` for the `if statement` will work with the constrained optimization. I thought some how nested optimization is involved, but I couldn't get anything to work. I provided known solutions to the problem from the IMSL optimization library to compare/check with. They are written below the optimization routine. Anyway, here is the code I've put together so far:

```
function [history] = testing()

% History
history.fval = [];
history.x = [];
history.a = []; 

%----------------
% Equations
polynomial = @(x,a) 2*sin(x)*a + 2*sin(2*x)*(9/20 -(4*a)/5) + 2*sin(3*x)*(a/5 - 2/15);
dpdx = @(x,a) 2*cos(x)*a + 4*cos(2*x)*(9/20 -(4*a)/5) + 6*cos(3*x)*(a/5 - 2/15);

% Upper limit of integration
IC = 0.8;       % initial
LB = 0;         % lower
UB = pi/2;      % upper

% Optimization
tol = 0.003;


% Coefficient
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dpda = @(x,a) 2*sin(x) + 2*sin(2*x)*(-4/5) + 2*sin(3*x)*1/5;
dEda = @(L,a) -2*integral(@(x) (x-polynomial(x,a)).*dpda(x,a),0,L);
a_of_L = @(L) fzero(@(a)dEda(L,a),0);                                   % Calculate the value of "a" for a given "L"
EXITFLAG = @(L) get_outputs(@()a_of_L(L),3);                            % Be sure a zero is actually calculated


% NL Constraints
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Equality constraint (No inequality constraints for parent optimization)
ceq = @(L) EXITFLAG(L) - 1; % Just make sure fzero finds unique solution 
confun = @(L) deal([],ceq(L));

% Objective function
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% (Set optimize=0 to test coefficent equations and proper maximization of L )
optimize = 1;

if optimize

%%%%  Plug in solution below

else 
    % Optimization options
    options = optimset('Algorithm','interior-point','Display','iter','MaxIter',500,'OutputFcn',@outfun);

    % Optimize objective
    objective = @(L) -L;
    xsol = fmincon(objective,IC,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,confun,options);

    % Known optimized solution from IMSL library
    % a = 0.799266;
    % lim = pi/2;
    disp(['IMSL coeff (a): 0.799266     Upper bound (L): ',num2str(pi/2)])
    disp(['code coeff (a): ',num2str(history.a(end)),'   Upper bound: ',num2str(xsol)])

end




    % http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921133/anonymous-functions-calling-functions-with-multiple-output-forms
    function varargout = get_outputs(fn, ixsOutputs)
        output_cell = cell(1,max(ixsOutputs));
        [output_cell{:}] = (fn());
        varargout = output_cell(ixsOutputs);
    end

    function stop = outfun(x,optimValues,state)
        stop = false;

        switch state
            case 'init'
            case 'iter'
                % Concatenate current point and objective function
                % value with history. x must be a row vector.
                history.fval = [history.fval; optimValues.fval];
                history.x = [history.x; x(1)];
                history.a = [history.a; a_of_L(x(1))];

            case 'done'
            otherwise
        end
    end
end
```

I could really use some help setting up the constrained optimization. I'm not only new to optimizations, I've never used MATLAB to do so. I should also note that what I have above does not work and is incorrect for the constrained optimization.

**UPDATE**: I added a for loop in the section `if optimize`to show what I'm trying to achieve with the optimization. Obviously, I could just use this, but it seems very inefficient, especially if I increase the resolution of `range` and have to run this optimization many times. If you uncomment the plots, it will show how the `bandwidth` behaves. By looping over the full range, I'm basically testing every `L` but surely there's got to be a more efficient way to do this??

**UPDATE**: Solved

Comment: @TT.: If a suggested edit introduces a mistake and you can't fix it, then you should reject it. The suggester can resubmit the edit after fixing the mistake in the image of the formula.

Comment: I've also been thinking about [complex step differentiation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/10/14/complex-step-differentiation/). However, note that you shouldn't really use an `epsilon` smaller than 1e-16, I'd probably go with something between 1e-10 and 1e-15. But it's best if you can compute the derivative on paper, and define an analytic differential as anonymous function.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yeah, yesterday I read that post in the link you provided and he used an epsilon of 1e-8 if I recall correctly. In the post I linked, where I pulled the code from, he used 1e-20. I was a little suspicious of that myself. I think I'll stick with 1e-8 to start, then increase it if need be. As for the derivative, yes I know it would be best to do on paper, but again the goal is to generalize this routine due to the number of polynomials I have to evaluate.

Comment: You should also consider that `dE/da=integral((x-polynomial).*dp/da)`. If you compute `dp/da` for one constraint, you can integrate that to get the other constraint. I'm not sure how much this helps. You could also compute `dp/da` with symbolic math (as long as it's polynomial, it should be fairly easy), and using `matlabFunction` on that simpler problem. I'm afraid it will need some tweaking whatever you do.

Comment: Also, your problem seems to be coming from that `fmincon` expects the objective function to accept vectorized input. However, `integral` only accepts scalar integral bounds. To work around this, you need to vectorize `Error()` yourself, for instance by using `arrayfun()` to compute the integral for every input value in `L`. However, you can speed it up a lot by looking at [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554474/get-integrated-vector-values/26557516#26557516), cancelling a lot of slow-down coming from using `integral()`. You might need a named function for this...

Comment: Yeah, I back tracked and I can't even evaluate polynomial(A,B), where A and B are vectors of arbitrary dimensions. I tried to vectorize polynomial and still not help there. (referring to my second attempt that is)....ahhh....ok...so making size(A)==size(B) fixes that

Comment: @ThatsRightJack oh that's right. When I suggested that, I hadn't considered vector-valued "a". If you use, for instance, `polynomial = @(x,a) 2*a(:).'*sin(x(:)) + 2*sin(2*x(:))*(9/20 -(4*a(:).')/5) + 2*sin(3*x(:))*(a(:).'/5 - 2/15);`, then the output will be of size `[numel(x),numel(a)]` in case of vector input. You can then `integrate()` this, just tell it that the function is `'arrayvalued'` (see the docs of `integrate`). Again, the dimensions of `L` can be introduced as column vectors... it's not too pretty, but it could be managed I think fairly easily. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry, you (=I) have to be more careful. In my previous comment the anon function should begin with `@(x,a) 2*sin(x(:))*a(:).'` in order to have a column-row matrix product. The rest of the terms are accidentally OK, at least they seem to be OK.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yeah, I caught that. One other thing, is the command you're suggesting `integrate` or `integral`? I've been using `integral`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106176/discussion-between-thatsrightjack-and-andras-deak).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Can you please take a look at my latest updates...specifically #4.

Comment: Quick answer (I don't know when I'll have time for a longer one): indeed, `IC` determines the size of the parameter set, so probably you should define `Error2` with a vector parameter argument, and pass on the two components to the functions called inside it. And yes, it's possible that the parameters need not be vectorized, but your earlier errors made me suspect this.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems `fmincon` is not the only tool for this job. In fact I couldn't even get it to work. Below, `fmincon` gets "stuck" on the IC and refuses to do anything...why...that's for a different post! Using the same layout and formulation, `fminbnd` finds the correct solution. The only difference, as far as I know, is that the former was using a conditional. But my conditional is nothing fancy, and really unneeded. So it's got to have something to do with the algorithm. I guess that's what you get when using a "black box". Anyway, after a long, drawn out, painful, learning experience, here is a solution:

```
options = optimset('Display','iter','MaxIter',500,'OutputFcn',@outfun);

% Conditional
index = @(L) min(find(abs([dpdx(range(range<=L),a_of_L(L)),inf] - 1) - tol > 0,1,'first'),length(range));

% Optimize
%xsol = fmincon(@(L) -range(index(L)),IC,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,confun,options);
xsol = fminbnd(@(L) -range(index(L)),LB,UB,options);
```

I would like to especially thank @AndrasDeak for all their support. I wouldn't have figured it out without the assistance!

Comment: I'm glad you got to figure it out:) Have fun with anonymous functions in the future;)